# Найти вопросы по объединению меток

Tags: поддержка, метки, поиск

Как найти вопросы по объединению меток, а не пересечению меток?

Например, `[cpp][c]` - вопросы с меткой [cpp](/questions/tagged/cpp) AND [c](/questions/tagged/c). А надо вопросы с хотя бы одной из этих меток.

Comment: @EOF а запрос нельзя составить?

Comment: `[cpp] or [c]` очевидно

Comment: @andreymal а где документация для синтаксиса?

Comment: Сразу же под строкой поиска висит ссылка [Справка по поиску](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для объединения меток надо использовать `[cpp] or [c]`, спасибо @andreymal.

[Как выполнять поиск?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/searching)